# Webpy: how to set http status code to 300

Tags: python, http-headers, http-status-codes, web.py

Maybe it is a stupid question but I cannot figure out how to a http status code in webpy.

In the documentation I can see a list of types for the main status codes, but is there a generic function to set the status code?

I'm trying to implement an `unAPI` server and it's required to reply with a `300 Multiple Choices` to a request with only an identifier. More info [here](http://unapi.info/specs/)

Thanks!

EDIT: I just discovered that I can set it through `web.ctx` doing

`web.ctx.status = '300 Multiple Choices'`

is this the best solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way web.py does this for 301 and other redirect types is by subclassing `web.HTTPError` (which in turn sets `web.ctx.status`). For example:

```
class MultipleChoices(web.HTTPError):
    def __init__(self, choices):
        status = '300 Multiple Choices'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        data = '<h1>Multiple Choices</h1>\n<ul>\n'
        data += ''.join('<li><a href="{0}">{0}</a></li>\n'.format(c)
                        for c in choices)
        data += '</ul>'
        web.HTTPError.__init__(self, status, headers, data)
```

Then to output this status code you `raise MultipleChoices` in your handler:

```
class MyHandler:
    def GET(self):
        raise MultipleChoices(['http://example.com/', 'http://www.google.com/'])
```

It'll need tuning for your particular unAPI application, of course.

See also [the source for `web.HTTPError` in webapi.py](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/webapi.py).

Comment: this method also do the job for 304 Not Modified in case you serve some image programmatically